# Implementing Touch Events on polygons

Tags: android, opengl-es, collision-detection

I've written some code that will find a cube's vertices coordinates in screen space after they've been multiplied by the MVP matrix. I want to check when the user taps, or touches the screen within a cube, and then do something.

I've seen methods for circle where you find the center of a circle, then calculate its radius and then you find the distances of the touchX, and touchY from the center of the circle, if the distance is less than the radius then the user is touching the circle.

```
    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        double distanceFromCenter = Math.sqrt((shapeCenterX - e.getX())^2 + (shapeCenterY - e.getY())^2);
        if (Math.abs(distanceFromCenter) < radius)
           {
            //Touch within circle...
        }
    }
```

I was  thinking I could find the center of the cube, and knowing where its vertices are, I'll find out how far the vertices are from the center. I'll then check the distance of the touchX, touchY from the center of the cube. If the distance is less than the radius then the user is touching the cube.

Would this work, and if not, what would I have to do to make it work?
Is this a good approach to collision detection for polygons?

Comment: This won't work. You can test it by drawing a square on paper and measuring the distances of the vertices to the center: they are at maximum distance. So there are lots of points with the same distance outside your square. Better check for each dimension wether the coordinates of the touch point are between the max and min values of the vertices' coordinates for each dimension.

Comment: To check if point is in projection of cube on screen (a polygon with at most 6 visible vertices) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html